# onsenui cannot change content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I’m using onsen ui version 1, followed https://onsen.io/v1/guide.html to make changes to DOM

This section to be exact

```
// Add another Onsen UI element
var content = document.getElementById("my-content");
content.innerHTML="<ons-button>Another Button</ons-button>";
ons.compile(content);
```

The problem is nothing changed on the page.

If i dump “content” variable or dump the HTML element it shows the newly edited version on browser console. but on page still the old one.

ons object is instantiated, compile method is callable, tried different HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are doing something incorrectly or it's an angular refresh issue.

For the first scenario it's easier if you provide a codepen, so that we can see the problem. Currently the code you are mentioning is working fine for me [here](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/zogzqN?editors=1010).

For the second scenario actually the third line `ons.compile(content);` should remove this problem imo, it might be a version issue, or there is some context which I am missing.

If you're doing something angular related then you should also show where you are calling these 3 lines from. In order to work it should be called from something like an `ng-` event (for example `ng-click`).

JS:

```
app.controller('yourControllerName', function($scope) {
    $scope.addButton = function () {
        var content = document.getElementById("my-content");
        content.innerHTML="<ons-button>Another Button</ons-button>";
        ons.compile(content);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ons-button ng-click="addButton()">Add another button</ons-button>
```

Finally if you are unable to make it work you can do something like

```
app.controller('yourControllerName', function($scope) {
    $scope.addButton = function () {
        var content = document.getElementById("my-content");
        content.innerHTML="<ons-button>Another Button</ons-button>";
        ons.compile(content);
        $scope.apply(); // should fix the issue, but not recommended
    }
});
```

PS: You can also try out onsen 2 - there you can:

- experiment with the [interactive tutorial](http://tutorial.onsen.io/)
- try out the vanilla version (without any external framework) - which will not have issues like this one